# Custom shipping method check weigh of product

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, product-weight

I followed this tutorial (https://magenticians.com/create-magento-2-shipping-module-method/) that showed me how to create a **custom shipping method**, but I still have one problem, i need to take into account the **weight** of the **product** to see if I can enable such **shipping method**, so i came here to see if anyone as any ideas how i can do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your Carrier (**collectRates** function)

```
  $qty = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems())
    {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item)
        {
            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren())
            {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child)
                {
                    if (! $child->getProduct()->isVirtual())
                    {
                        $qty += $child->getQty();
                    }
                }
            } else
            {

                $qty += $item->getQty();
            }
        }
    }
$final_qty = $qty;
```

Comment: I did that, but i still don't see no diference

Comment: did you got the qty? if you got it you need to check if it is valid quantity then you need to continue to add the shipping method by this (  $result->append($method)).

Comment: @WISAMHAKIM can you please explain logic of above code?

Comment: @Khushbu, the above code is only get the quantities of current cart products, it was requested in this Question, i think it was needed for special logic